# Loading .html and .js with websockets

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have the idea of having something like a web server but without a web server. Instead I want to use websockets. Is for internal use.

The user will have a basic webpage which will only open a websocket connection and should receive an .html, and immediately navigate to it.
Also it should be able to load a .js with helper functions for this new html.

I saw here something to load an image file
http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/11/12-pushing-files-to-the-browser-using-deliveryjs-socketio-and-nodejs/
but I don't know how to navigate to a received .html file and how to execute a received .js file.

Do not try to convince me of using a webserver or other technologies, I have my reaasons for doing this :-)
Thanks

Comment: Just out of interest - what is the reasons? :)

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's better to use a WebSocket than a plain web server. Please explain.

Comment: I have already a running websocket server, and I don't want to use/learn another technology.

Comment: I think you would be better off learning the correct technology for this.

Comment: As expected people is triying to convince me :-) I will not do it for the moment. Thanks

Comment: No I don't think you understand. You need to use the correct technology or I will get very anxious and not be able to function for at least three days.

Comment: I found a nice way here: http://technify.me/user-experience/javascript/executing-javascript-in-an-ajax-response/  I will try but with websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Using a websocket inherently means you need to use a server. A websocket is be definition a connection between the client and the server.

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

> WebSockets is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

Regarding running a javascript file that you have downloaded, you can use `eval`, or you can create a new script tag on the body to load your javascript.

Comment: Yes, I have already a running websocket server, from which I would like to send the .js and .html files

Comment: Nice to know about eval. I will try. Thanks